I want to make a telegram bot which can record voice channel activites like who mwas joining tha vc and to thew the audio of the vc . How to make it?
I want to make a telegram bot which can record voice channel activites like who mwas joining tha vc and to thew the audio of the vc . How to make it ?
I searched about it in google but didn't find any reference..
tried to make a vc tracker telegram bot ..
